# Inverse of the anti-commutator

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, inverse

Let $B \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a fixed $n \times n$ symmetric positive matrix. Consider the anti-commutator map

$$f:M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$$

via

$$f(C)=BC+CB$$

We can prove that $f$ is an injective linear operator and thus invertible. (Find a basis so that B is diagonal and everything is clear.) My question:

Is there a good expression for $f^{-1}$?

I am looking for an expression for $f^{-1}(D)$ as some polynomial or power series in terms of $B, B^{-1}, D$.

Comment: When you have a function y=f (x), to get the inverse you interchange x and y, then solve for y.  I would try this here with C and D, for starters.

Comment: Notably, this is an example of a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Answer (score 0):

We can use the more general result solving the [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation).  We wish to solve the equation
$$
BC + CB^H = D
$$
for $D$.  We changing the sign of both sides, we note that $-B$ is stable (in the sense that its eigenvalues have negative real part).  We then find that
$$
(-B)C + C(-B)^H = -D \implies\\
C = \int_0^\infty e^{-B\tau}(-D)e^{-B\tau}\,d\tau = -\int_0^\infty e^{-B\tau}De^{-B\tau}\,d\tau
$$

So, we may write our inverse as
$$
f^{-1}(D) = -\int_0^\infty e^{-B\tau}De^{-B\tau}\,d\tau
$$
Of course, this uses a matrix-valued integral, and $e^{-B \tau}$ is implicitly a series on $B$.

---

If we write this map as a matrix with respect to the canonical basis of $M_{n \times n}$ (as is somewhat explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))), we find that
$$
[f]_{\mathcal B} = I \otimes B + B^T \otimes I 
$$
and so, we're ultimately looking for the inverse of the sum of the two commuting matrices $I \otimes B$ and $B^T \otimes I$.  We can get this inverse as a power series, though I'm not sure we can guarantee its convergence.

Let $M = I \otimes B + B^T \otimes I$. We have
$$
(I \otimes B^{-1})M = I+ B^T \otimes B^{-1}
$$
From there, we have
$$
I+ B^T \otimes B^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k[[B^T] \otimes B^{-1}]^k
$$
Moreover, 
$$
[(I \otimes B^{-1})M]^{-1} = M^{-1}(I \otimes B) = (I \otimes B)M^{-1}
$$
All together,
$$
M^{-1} = (I \otimes B)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k[B^T \otimes B^{-1}]^k
$$
Translated back into operators, we have
$$
f^{-1}(D) = B \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k(B^{-k}D + DB^k)
$$
However, we have no reason to suspect that this sum should converge.  Notably, with the $2$-norm, we find that
$$
\|B^T \otimes B^{-1}\| = (\lambda_{max}(BB^T \otimes (BB^T)^{-1}))^{1/2} = \|B\| \cdot \|B^{-1}\| \geq 1
$$

---

A strategy to get around non-convergence may be as follows: for $t > 0$, the function 
$$
f_t(C) =  t\,BC + CB
$$
has inverse
$$
f_t^{-1}(C) = t^{-1} B \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k t^{-k} (B^{-k}D + DB^k)
$$
and we can guarantee that this series converges for sufficiently large values of $t$.  Perhaps we could then take a limit as $t \to 1^+$ of the resulting expression.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ has the eigenvalues $t_1,\dots,t_n$, then the eigenvalues of $f=f_B$ are $(t_i+t_j)_{1\le i\le j}$. So the characteristic polynomial of $f_B$ is $P(X)=\prod_{i,j}(X-t_i-t_j)$. This polynomial is known: $P(X)$ is (maybe up to sign) equal to the resultant of $\chi(Y)$ and $\chi(X-Y)$, where $\chi(X)=\prod_i(X-t_i)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $B$ and the resultant is computed viewing terms as polynomials on $Y$. Write $P(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}m_iX^i$ ($m_{n^2}=1$; the other coefficients can be explicitly computed using a formula on the resultant, or using roots: e.g. $m_0=(-1)^n\prod_{i,j}(t_i+t_j)$). Then $P(f_B)=0$. So
$$f_B^{-1}(C)=-m_0^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n^2-1}m_{i+1}f_B^{i}(C)$$
for all $C$.